Linearity implies locally Lipschitz
A function $f(\cdot,\cdot):U \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is called locally Lipschitz with respect to second variable in $(t_0, x_0) \in U$ if $\exists U_0 \in \mathcal{V}(t_0,x_0)$ (neighborhood) and $\exists L \ge 0$ such that $\|f(t,x)-f(t,y)\| \le L \|x-y\| \forall (t,x),(t,y) \in U \cap U_0$.
Now, I want to prove that if I have a function $f:I \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n, f(t,x) = A(t) x$, where $A(\cdot):I \to M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a continuous matrix valued function,then $f$ is locally Lipschitz with respect to second variable in any point.
I observe that $f$ is linear in the second variable, because $f(t,ax+by)=A(t)(ax+by)=a(A(t)x)+b(B(t)y)=af(t,x)+bf(t,y)$ and I saw in a comment that if $f$ is linear in the second variable, then is locally Lipschitz with respect to second variable in every point, but I don't understand why...

Take a point $(t_0, x_0) \in U$ and $h > 0$ small enough so that $[t_0 - h, t_0 + h] \times V$ is contained in $U$ for $V$ some neighbourhood of $x_0$. The $U_0$ we'll consider is then $(t_0 - h, t_0 + h) \times V$.
Since $t \mapsto \|A(t)\|$ (the norm used is the operator norm tied to the currently unspecified norm imposed on $\mathbb{R}^n$ here) is continuous on $[t_0 - h, t_0 + h]$ a compact set, it is bounded above by some $L \geq 0$.
We then have, for $(t,x) \in U_0$ :
$$\|f(t,x) - f(t,y)\| = \|A(t) (x - y)\| \leq \|A(t)\| \|x - y\| \leq L \|x - y\|$$
and so $f$ is locally Lipschitz in the second variable as desired.
